# Comparing specific columns of two csv files

Tags: c#, csv

I have two csv files with like 18 columns each...I would like with c# to compare the first column of the first file with the first column of the second file and the third column of the first with the third column of the second and when a difference is found,I want to be saved to another file so the third file should have as an output two columns.So somehow I need to tell which is the first column and which is the third column and then compare.

Any suggestions how can i achieve this?

Comment: import it into excel or spreadsheet,  whichever is applicable, and then check ,why C#??

Comment: Where is the problem? Have you got the CSVs imported into a data structure? Is the problem actually just reading the CSVs? You should narrow down this question a bit - currently it is far too broad.

Comment: @Anonymous: One would imagine because he is trying to do it programatically... a major point of programming is automation. Saying "Why not do it manually?" isn't a very helpful comment...

Comment: just a suggestion, if he is doing it for hobby then i wont restrict.

Comment: I might need to do a GUI after I manage and see that my code works and does the job.So I find making a GUI from visual studio easier.That's all

Comment: @Chris My csv files are going to be downloaded from a ftp server to my pc then I just need to read them .It is most likely products that will be updated from the ftp server so I need to see if new products have been added to the new csv file,while comparing with the old that I will have downloaded

Comment: @Konstantinos: the point I was trying to make is not that I wanted more detail on what you were doing but that your question should focus on one part of what you are doing. If you are having problems reading the CSV files then post a question about that. If once you've got them in a data structure you are having problems doing the comparison then post another question about that, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The basics are reading each file line by line and then splitting each string. With a CSV file you typically have a comma as seperator, but this could be a tab or similar char as well. So use the one you have. You then get something similar to

```
        string line;
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.csv");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var arr = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });
            // do your comparison
        }
```

though you nee to open 2 files. You can then compare the array from file 1 with the array from file 2 (index into array == column, starting at 0). Smilarly, you can use String.Join to create your output again.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this simple csv parsing may work but if you have escaped commas (ie in quotes) then this will split wrongly...

Comment: You are right. String.Split works fine on Chars - with Chars being stuff like ',', '\t', ' ' and the like. If you have a seperator of several chars, you might have to trim the string you get afterwards, either by using String.Trim or by using String.Substring, whereas with String.Substring you would have to do quite a few calculations.

Comment: Andreas: My point is that if I want to encode `Hi, Andreas` as field one and `Hola, Andreas` as field 2 then in a CSV it would be `"Hi, Andreas","Hola, Andreas"`. Splitting this on comma without worrying about whether the comma is in quotes or not will do the wrong thing.

Comment: Ok, never came across this (but have only worked with most basic CSV files). My understanding was that you would simply use a tab instead of a , (always wondered why they are called CSV if they are "any seperator seperated values") when creating the file. Should it be with "", you would have to add some logic going through the result array and reconcatinating single entries, then trimming. (Or write your own split code. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15361/Split-Function-that-Supports-Text-Qualifiers) In that case, there might be (a lot?) easier solutions. All depends on the CSV format.

Comment: Yeah. Your method often works and if it is just numeric (for example) you'd never have problems. You just need to be aware of your data and what it might look like. This is one of those reasons why its generally advised to find a pre-existing parser. Last time I wrote a CSV parser though I ended up having to write a state machine and go through character by character. If you want to see an example of this sort of format just save an excel file with a comma in a cell as a CSV and you should see the way it works.

Answer (score 0):

browse 2 excel sheets to a 2 Datatable. Comapre 2 tables and if there is difference put it in the new table.

Finally export the table to Excel.