# How to compare 2 .csv files and create a new .csv containing parts from both csv files?

Tags: c#, file, csv

I am trying to compare two specific parts of CSV files.

```
JobStart.csv
test1;test2;test3;test4;Val2Compare2;test5;test6;test7....

Datafile.csv
line 1   Val2Compare1; data1;data2;data3;data4;data5;data6
line 2   Val2Compare2; data1;data2;data3;data4;data5;data6
line 3   Val2Compare3; data1;data2;data3;data4;data5;data6
```

---

What I want to do is:

Compare values: JobStart.csv Val2Compare2 to

```
     Datafile.csv          Val2Compare1
                           Val2Compare2
                           Val2Compare3
                           ...
```

When I got which line is true (in this case line2). Then I want to combine JobStat.csv and Datafile.csv like so:

```
NEW JOBSTART.CSV


test1;test2;test3;test4;Val2Compare2;test5;test6;test7; data1;data2;data3;data4;data5
```

I tried to look at:

[Compare two csv file using in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154370/compare-two-csv-file-using-in-c-sharp)

[Comparing specific columns of two csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880894/comparing-specific-columns-of-two-csv-files)

[Compare 2 csv files and replace updated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526730/compare-2-csv-files-and-replace-updated-values)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3f334045-2ac7-44b9-afaa-bd8d83c8ef27/read-csv-file-and-get-specific-column-from-each-line?forum=csharpgeneral

But couldn't get much help.

Comment: Use md5. Read sting for both of them and convert string to md5 and compare md5s.

Comment: It sounds like you find a match between line 1 of JobStart and line 2 of Datafile. How do you then know to combine line 1 of Datafile? What's the rule?

Comment: @acfrancis maybe I wasn't good inof explaining my issue. I want to compare JobStart.csv PART[5] to first column of Datafile.csv untill it match.

Comment: I got that but you then combine the files into NEW JOBSTART including data1, etc which is in line 1 of Datafile.

Comment: @acfrancis that was a mistake from my side. I have edited Datafile.csv so that line 1 line 2 line 3 all have data1 etc. (This kind of mistakes occur when you copy paste) :)

Comment: OK, that seems clear enough. What part of the code are you stuck on?

Comment: @acfrancis The first part which compares and the second part which creates file are both my STUCK points. I tried different thing but in matter of fact i deleted all the code without having any kind of back up. Now I am here with nothing. (I know it's bad excuse).

Comment: Does JobStart have only one line? Can it match more than one line in Datafile?

Comment: yes JobStart.csv is one line. JobStart part[5] have only one match in Datafile.csv or non.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var jobStartLine = File.OpenText(@"JobStart.csv").ReadLine();
var comparisonField = jobStartLine.Split(';')[4];

foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(@"Datafile.csv"))
{
    var fields = line.Split(new char[] {';'}, 2);
    if (comparisonField == fields[0])
    {
        File.WriteAllLines(@"NewJobStart.csv", new string[] { jobStartLine + ";" + fields[1] });
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx. This works fine but it copy data1 only [data2... etc] doesn't get copied. to NewJobStart.csv file. I need to + fields[2]... fields[5] ?

Comment: There was a small mistake in the call to Split(). Try the updated code.

Comment: What if I don't want (fields[last]) which in this case is data5 in my NewJobStart.csv file, how can i do that? 

I want to declare data6 as gobal char[]. 

I tried: class with a public Char[]. myclass.MyChar = fields[6].tochararray();

Comment: If you don't want all the fields, change the call to ``Split()`` removing the last parameter (in my code "2"). Then you need to add only the fields you want to the output line (inside the call to ``WriteAllLines()``). In any case, I would treat the fields as ``string``s not ``Char[]`` unless you really have to.