# How to Ignore a field and set the ignored field as a global variable within the function?

Tags: c#, global-variables, field

I have this code to combine 2 different csv files.

```
try
{
    var jobStartLine = File.OpenText(PackAuftrag).ReadLine();
    var comparisonField = jobStartLine.Split(';')[4];

    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(BoxData))
    {
        var fields = line.Split(new char[] {';'}, 2);

        if (comparisonField == fields[0])
        {
            File.WriteAllLines(JobStart, 
                               new string[] {jobStartLine + ";" + fields[1]});
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

My BoxData = `data1;data2;data3;data4;data5`

At the moment data2 to data5 is getting in JobStart file.

Data5 shouldn't be included inside JobStart file.

I want to set data5 as a global variable.

How can I do this, I just cannot figure this out, need help.

This can help understanding my problem: [How to compare 2 .csv files and create a new .csv containing parts from both csv files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951138/how-to-compare-2-csv-files-and-create-a-new-csv-containing-parts-from-both-csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I sovled my problem:

```
  if (File.Exists(JobStart))
        {
            File.Delete(JobStart);
        }

        try
        {
            var jobStartLine = File.OpenText(PackAuftrag).ReadLine();
            var comparisonField = jobStartLine.Split(';')[4];

         foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(BoxData))
            {
                var fields = line.Split(new char[] { ';' }, 2);



                if (comparisonField == fields[0])
                {

                    string string2write = "";
                    string2write += JobName + ',';
                    string2write += jobStartLine.Split(';')[0] + ',';
                    string2write += jobStartLine.Split(';')[1] + ',';
                    string2write += jobStartLine.Split(';')[2] + ',';
                    string2write += jobStartLine.Split(';')[3] + ',';
                    string2write += jobStartLine.Split(';')[5] + ',';
                    string2write += line.Split(';')[1] + ',';
                    string2write += line.Split(';')[2] + ',';

                    string2write += line.Split(';')[3] + ',';
                    string2write += line.Split(';')[4] + ',';
                    string2write += line.Split(';')[5] + ',';
                    string2write += line.Split(';')[6];
                    PrinterSelected = line.Split(';')[7];

                    FileStream fst = new FileStream(JobStart, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                    StreamWriter stw = new StreamWriter(fst, Encoding.Default);
                    stw.Write(string2write);
                    stw.Dispose();
                    stw.Close();

//                        File.WriteAllLines(JobStart, new string[] { jobStartLine + ";" + fields[1]});


                    break;
                }
```

Comment: This is not the best solution, but even if you wanted to proclaim your own answer as the right one from the start, you should at least know that you should use StringBuilder instead of "+=" and to use "using" instead of just forgetting to dispose/close streams. All the best.

Comment: @LepiPerke I didn't marked it as a "best" answer but more like "how I did it" I am not the best programmer at all. On the other hand I am new programmer of C#... But thx for your advice

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = string.Empty;

try
{
    var jobStartLine = File.OpenText(PackAuftrag).ReadLine();
    var comparisonField = jobStartLine.Split(';')[4];

    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(BoxData))
    {
        var fields = line.Split(new char[] {';'}, 5).ToList();
        foo = fields[4];
        fields.RemoveAt(4);

        if (comparisonField == fields[0])
        {
            File.WriteAllLines(JobStart, 
                           new string[] {jobStartLine + ";" + String.Join(';', fields.ToArray())});
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This kinda resolves what I understood to be your problem.